# data not pass using ajax after onclick

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to remove an element from the database. 
I don't know why, but the data is not getting to the url i inserted.
this is the code (the obj is indeed faded - only in the client side):

```
   $(document).on("click", "#deleteAdmin", function(e) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "admin/adminProccess.php",
        type: "get",
        data: $('#idPriv:checked').serialize()  + '&str=' + 'deleteAdmin',
        success: function(data) {

                $('#idPriv:checked').each(function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                });

                 var item = $(deleteAdmin);
                 item.fadeOut();



    }
});
});
```

is there something wrong in my code?
when i'm trying to access manually to the url i can see some results - but with my code its not sending the data.

any ideas?

**edit:** this is my idPriv:

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="idPriv[]" id="idPriv"  onclick="evaluateIT(this)" data-related-item="adminPanelShow" value ="<?php echo $value["id"].':'. $count; ?>" />
```

Comment: name='idPriv[]',are you have more than one checkbox and you are using a same id?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$('#idPriv:checked').serialize() + '&str=' + 'deleteAdmin'
```

to:

```
$('#idPriv:checked').val() + '&str=' + 'deleteAdmin'
```

Comment: What is your `#idPriv`? Can you post your HTML markup?